# Chain rule with constraints

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am self-learning about the partial derivative with constraint in the online course Multivariable Calculus of MIT OpenCourseware and I'm struggling at understanding the exercise below (as shown by the image).

My question is that:  In this problem,   $f(x,y,z)$ and  $g(x,y)$ is basically the same thing.
But why the gradient of  $ f(x,y,z) $ has 3 components when the gradient vector of $ g(x,y)$ only has 2 components ?
Moreover, why the gradient of $ f(x,y,z)$ has 3 components when it is radically a function of $(x,y)$ ?

Thank you very much for your help!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$ and $f$ are not the same. And the way how the gradient of $g$ is found is not an explicit application of the chain rule as one could expect from the title of the chapter.

So, I give here the solution to the problem by a direct application of the chain rule.

The situation is as follows

$$\mathbb{R}^2\stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}^3\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}$$
with

$$h(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z(x,y)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\y^2-x^3\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } g=f\circ h$$

Now, the chain rule gives

$$\nabla g(1,2) = \nabla f(1,2,z(1,2))D_h(1,2)$$ where
$$D_h(x,y) =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\\partial_x z(x,y) & \partial_y z(x,y) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\-3x^2 & 2y \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence,

$$\nabla g(1,2) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\-3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-8 & 10\end{pmatrix}$$